# Placing different Materialize toasts in different positions of the screen [ version: 1.0.0 ]

Tags: css, materialize

I want to display a toast on the top-middle of screen when image is zoomed-in and other normal toasts to be displayed at default position. I've managed to show toasts when zoomed-in but unable to position the toasts.

I've already tried altering "#toast-container" but, it places all toasts at same position of screen.

```
#toast-container {
  top: auto !important;
  right: auto !important;
  bottom: 10%;
  left:3%;  
}
```

Expected: 
toast 1: top-middle of screen and toast 2: top-right or bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are asking without adding some code (MaterializeCSS has nothing baked into the core for positioning toasts); however, you can add a class to `#toast-container` with some jQuery after you initialize your toast. Then you can style that class.

**Option 1:**

For Example:

```
// Initialize Toast
var duration = 3000;
Materialize.toast('Toast Message', duration, 'rounded');
// Add Class to Container
$('#toast-container').addClass('bottom-right');
// OPTIONAL : Remove Class from Container after Timeout
setTimeout(() => $('#toast-container').removeClass('bottom-right'), duration);
```

Then just create CSS classes to overwrite the core CSS as needed.

For Example:

```
#toast-container.bottom-right {
    top: unset;
    bottom: 10%;
}
#toast-container.bottom-left {
    top: unset;
    right: unset;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 7%;
}
```

**Option 2:**

You can apply classes to the `.toast` element and give it `position: fixed` to place it anywhere you want.

With all that said, the animations are going to be problematic, so you might have to wrestle with those a bit... or just turn animation off completely by setting `.toast` to `transition: none !important`

*Source: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/658*